# Excel Interop - insert & add data by row

Tags: c#, excel

Hey guys I need to insert empty rows below a certain row in an excel and then add data into those empty rows I inserted...

So far I am able to create empty rows but I am having a hell of a time trying to figure out how to set Range.Value to an array of type String

Method for inserting Rows:

```
private void shiftRows(int from, int numberof)
    {
        from++;
        Range r = oXL.get_Range("A" + from.ToString(), "A" + from.ToString()).EntireRow;

        for (int i = 0; i < numberof; i++)
            r.Insert(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftDown);
    }
 // so this would shift the below rows by numberof times.
```

This method is currently what I am stuck on... which is inserting an array into the new rows one row at a time

```
    public void inputRowData(string[] data, int rds)
    {
        int bestRow = getRowByRDS(rds);
        string val = getValueOfCell(bestRow, 6);
        if (val == null || val.Equals(""))
        {
            shiftRows(bestRow, data.Length);
            string[] formatedData = formatOutput(bestRow, data);
            for (int i = 0; i < formatedData.Length; i++)
            {
                Range r = oSheet.get_Range((bestRow + i).ToString() + ":" + (bestRow + i).ToString());
                r.set_Value(formatedData[i].Split('\t'));

// have tried r.Value = formatedData[i].Split('\t')
// formatedData is an array of string which contains data for each cell seperated by a tab

            }

        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Line has some information already, skipping 1 more");
            shiftRows(bestRow, data.Length + 1);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly advise you:

- **NOT** to insert rows but just write empty row instead (safety and performance)
- to set a big array object and do only **ONE** write in excel (performance)

example (i kept the shiftrows but you should really get rid of it):

```
public void inputRowData(string[] data, int rds)
{
    int bestRow = getRowByRDS(rds);
    string val = getValueOfCell(bestRow, 6);
    if (val == null || val.Equals(""))
    {
        shiftRows(bestRow, data.Length);
        string[] formatedData = formatOutput(bestRow, data);
        // transform formated data into string[,]
        var string[][] splitedData = formatedData.Select(s => s.Split('\t')).ToArray();
        var colCount = splitedData.Max(r => r.Lenght);
        var excelData = new string[splitedData.Length, colCount]
        for (int i = 0; i < splitedData.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < splitedData[i].Length; j++)
            {
                 excelData[i,j] = splitedData[i][j];
            }
        }
        oSheet.get_Range("A" + bestRow.ToString()).Resize(splitedData.Length, colCount).Value = excelData;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Line has some information already, skipping 1 more");
        shiftRows(bestRow, data.Length + 1);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by writing empty rows please. How would I write empty rows between 2 current rows?

Comment: Say you have data from line 1 to 100. you want to insert 20 lines starting at row 50. I advise you to write 70 lines (the 20 you want + the 50 after) starting at row 50.

Comment: Well that would require me to copy the contents of the other 50 lines.

Comment: yes but this is very cheap ... just try to benchmark it, you'll see the difference, without speaking of the safety (with insertion, some named cells may move or it may have impact on data aside your columns or it may trigger unwanted events) ... Again, better to benchmark it to get your own opinion