# How to create a Excel Row and insert it in Excel Range?

Tags: c#, excel, range, office-interop

I have an excel worksheet as below (just an example)

[image]

I have created a `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range` object referring the range from Item1 to Category5 (selected cells in the above image).

Now I want to create a new Row (Market1, Market2, Market3, Market4, Market5) and add it below the range ie., below Category row.

I am using the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`classes for the first time.
Can someone help me in figuring out how to **create** and **add** a new row to an existing range object.

Here is the code which I have written -

```
public class Class1
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application appExcel = new Application();


        WorkBook workBook = appExcel.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Data.xlsx", true, false);
        workSheet = (Worksheet)workBook.Sheets["Export"];

        Range usedRange = workSheet.UsedRange;

        Range itemCatRange = GetSection(usedRange, "Item1","Group1"); //Gets the selected range as shown in pic

        //Here I want to create a new row of cells and add the newly created row at the end of the above range "itemCatRange"
    }

    private static Range GetSection(Range usedRange, string startHeader, string endHeader)
    {
        string str = string.Empty;
        string end = String.Empty;

        Range algAlmRange;
        foreach (Range row in usedRange.Rows)
        {

            object firstColumnValue = row.Columns.Value2[1, 1];
            if (firstColumnValue != null)
            {
                if (firstColumnValue.ToString() == startHeader)
                {
                    str = row.Address;
                }
                else if (firstColumnValue.ToString() == endHeader)
                {
                    end = row.Address;
                }

            }
        }

        algAlmRange = workSheet.Range[str, end];
        return algAlmRange;
    }
}
```

Comment: These might help: [Excel Interop - insert & add data by row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30495407/excel-interop-insert-add-data-by-row) , [Excel insert rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418776/excel-insert-rows-not-add)

Comment: Have you tried something? Please share your code

Comment: Thank u mohammed for ur response. I have added the code to the post.

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
Range itemCatRange = GetSection(usedRange, "Item1","Group1");
Range lastRow = itemCatRange[itemCatRange.Rows, 1].EntireRow;
lastRow.Insert(XlDirection.xlDown, XlInsertFormatOrigin.xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove);
```

You may have to go down another row, or use `xlUp`. I haven't actually tried this.

Comment: Thank u reasra :)
This solution works for inserting an empty row at the end of the range, but I want to create a new row and add it at the end of the range.

Comment: maybe `Range nextRow = workSheet.Cells[lastRow.Row + 1, 1].EntireRow` and then `nextRow.Insert`... but yea, I don't think `xlUp` is working correctly.